# Black screen with message

Tags: 12.04, boot, bios, pxe, media

Whenever I start my laptop there comes a black screen with message as shown in the image below.

[image]

After shutting down and restarting again and again 10-20 times (sometimes more than 20 times) it gets started and I always set boot priority  as Ubuntu first and then Windows, but after this shutting down and restarting process the boot priority gets changed and Windows becomes the first priority.

Comment: Hard Disk is visible in BIOS in the main section.

Fixed HDD : (Value)750GB
.
And what do you mean by internal disk and cable ?

Comment: Boot Order is 
LEGACY BOOT:
Network,
Hard Drive,  
CD/DVD

Comment: Does boot order need to be changed ?

Comment: What is the default order ? Why hard disk needs to be above network ?

Comment: see my answer. Ill clean up my comments ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common reasons for this:

1. you hard disk is not detected and the boot order in BIOS skips it and then ends up  picking network boot (PXE is related to network). This can happen if the cable in your system that is attached to the hard disk is faulty or is not connected firmly. If you open BIOS and the hard disk is detected this is NOT the cause.
2. Your boot order has a boot order where "network" comes before "hard drive". The item you want to boot off should to be the 1st in the line of boot options. (you could put the DVD 1st but it will take a bit of time for the system to skip booting from it and picking the next option). In general it is best to put the hard disk 1st and change the boot order when you need another option (like when installing from DVD/USB).

Comment: I changed the BIOS settings. It's difficult to tell at this time if it works. If the problem mentioned doesn't repeat, I'll let you know .

Comment: Now its showing black screen with message "Read Error_" only. What should i do now?